# Format/covert JS object string to valid JSON format

Tags: javascript, json

Given a STRING (not object) that represents JS object.

`'{a: {b: 1}}'` (not object but string)

Is there some simple general way to convert it to JSON `{"a": {"b": 1}}`? Maybe parse and covert, as `JSON.parse` is not applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no other content than this, you could take `eval` with parentheses around to prevent that it is interpreted as a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) with [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Maybe worth a look:

- [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197769/)

```js
var string = '{a: {b: 1}}',
    object = eval(`(${string})`);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Right thanks, forgot about eval at all, anyway it is quite applicable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var string = '{a: {b: 1}}';
eval('var obj='+string);
console.log(obj.a);
```